# Fb like button is not working on popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, facebook, popup

I have a WordPress websites in which i created a popup for form. I want to show the fb like button on that popup. But whenever i put the code under the popup the popup is stop working.

```
function message()
    { 
       jQuery(".snp-content-inner").html('<br><h2>Check your email for your Promotion Link! </h2><br><div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/inkgility?_rdr=p" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div><center><br><br><a onclick="return closepopup()" style="padding:8px 8px 8px 8px; color:#fff;" class="inf-submit" href="#">Enter Site</a></center>');

    }
```

if i am putting this fb code anywhere in page then it is working fine but when i set it here it stops working

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: is jQuery available in that popup? do you use the facebook library for the like plugin?

Comment: yes i have updated the query too in my question which i am using

Comment: dont post code in comments, please edit your question

Comment: Oh sorry please check now

Comment: When i put my div to anywhere in site it is working fine but in this code it is not working

Comment: You need to call FB.XFBML.parse(); after the popup opens to render the Like buttons you've dynamically added to the page.